# Where are the missing build files for performing a kernel bisection?

Tags: installation, kernel, debugging

I am attempting my first-ever kernel bisection to try and help debug a [regression](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1251441) that occurred somewhere between 13.04 and 13.10. I am trying to follow the instructions listed at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBisection#Bisecting_Ubuntu_kernel_versions , but I am unable to find all the build files needed to install a kernel version.

For example, I am attempting to install the [Saucy 3.8.0-19.29 kernel for amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.8.0-19.29/+build/4499991). The linked wiki page above says I should find files similar to these:

```
linux-headers-2.6.35-32-generic-pae_2.6.35-32.68_i386.deb (793.3 KiB)
linux-headers-2.6.35-32_2.6.35-32.68_all.deb (9.9 MiB)
linux-image-2.6.35-32-generic-pae_2.6.35-32.68_i386.deb (32.5 MiB)
```

However, from the linked build page, the closest I can find are just these:

```
linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic_3.8.0-19.29_amd64.deb (973.7 KiB)
linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic_3.8.0-19.29_amd64.deb (11.8 MiB)
```

If I try to just download these and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, I am given the following output with errors installing the headers:

```
christopher@SaucyBisectionTest:~/Downloads/3.8.0-19.29$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
[sudo] password for christopher: 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic.
(Reading database ... 193537 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic (from linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic_3.8.0-19.29_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic (from linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic_3.8.0-19.29_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic:
 linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic depends on linux-headers-3.8.0-19; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.8.0-19 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic (3.8.0-19.29) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f` .

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That removes the `linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic` package I think I need installed for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The missing "all" package I still needed was located under the build page for the i386 version.